# How to encapsule a php app?

Tags: php

I wrote an application with php, html5 and mysql and I need to install it to several clients servers. I want to hide the application so that my clients wont be able to see my code. I know that I can put a username and password to Mysql but if they watch my connect.php they would be able to access it. Is there a way where I can encapsule my app in such a way that nobody would be able to see it, just like in Java there is JAR.

Comment: A JAR file doesn't really hide anything.

Comment: Have a look at ioncube and similar softwares.

Comment: Again, if you don't want clients to see your sourcecode then host it yourself and sell it as a service. That's the best way. Solutions such as encryption or obfuscation are just a matter of time before they circumvent it. Also, as a client why should I ever install something that's obfuscated?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is "sort-of". There are tools that will encode your PHP, but they are easily defeated by anyone who really wants to get around it.

You should look into offering your "Software as a Service".